# overriding AsyncHttpResponseHandler

Tags: android, par

Guys while overriding **AsyncHttpResponseHandler** in parsing how do you get a string in android studio instead of (int response,header[] headers,byte[] bytes,) how does it work.

Comment: Please post your code what you have tried and then you get any help.

Comment: You can convert bytes[] to string. As @Soham said, post some code

Comment: @Soham its about json parsing in android studio when you override the method AsyncHttpResponseHandler your get public void  (int response,header[] headers,byte[] bytes) but instead i wanted the override to take (String response) that i get from the website.

Comment: @playmaker420 how do your convert bytes to String.

Comment: You can make a string from bytes[]  String myString = new String(bytes[]);

Comment: if (bytes != null) { String s = new String(bytes);}. Something like this. Google!

Comment: @playmaker420 thanks budy i'll try that out.

Comment: I guess you are using loopj asynchronous httpclient for network calls.

Comment: @playmaker420 yeah dude you got it

Comment: @playmaker420 thanx dude i actually completed making my app

Comment: @kevinjones4199 Congratz

Comment: @kevinjones4199 how were you able to achieve this?